# XML and XPath handling in VBA

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I'm trying to parse a XML into a spreadsheet using VBA, and for some reason I can't to the node that I want using XPath, here how my XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cteProc xmlns="http://www.somesite.com" versao="3.00">
 <CTe xmlns="http://www.somesite.com">
  <infCte Id="an id" versao="3.00">
    <ide>
     <cUF>23</cUF>
     <cCT>00000557</cCT>
     <CFOP>6932</CFOP>
     <natOp>some text </natOp>
     <mod>57</mod>
    </ide>
    <compl>
      <xObs>TEXT</xObs>
    </compl>
  </infCte>
 </CTe>
</cteProc>
```

I'm trying to get at least to the **ide** node, so I can loop over the rest and get the information I want.

My code looks like this:

```
Public Sub parseXml()

Dim oXMLFile As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim nodes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList

path2 = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\adoc.xml"

Set oXMLFile = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

oXMLFile.Load (path2)

Set nodes = oXMLFile.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/CTe")
```

So I tried to print the length of the nodes, I get this:

```
debug.print nodes.length

> 0
```

if I loop over like this:

```
Public Sub parseXml()

Dim oXMLFile As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim nodes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim node As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

path2 = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\adoc.xml"

Set oXMLFile = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

oXMLFile.Load (path2)


Set nodes = oXMLFile.DocumentElement.ChildNodes


For Each node In nodes
    Debug.Print node.BaseName
Next node
```

I get this:

```
> CTe
```

So, If I do a giant loop I can get the information I want, but I think there must be a simpler sulution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `XML` uses namespaces, `XPath` also needs to deal with namespaces.

The following works for me using your `XML`:

```
Public Sub parseXml()

 Dim oXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
 Dim oNodes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
 Dim oItem As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
 Dim path2 As String
 
 path2 = "P:\adoc.xml"

 Set oXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

 oXML.Load path2
 oXML.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
 oXML.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:ssc=""http://www.somesite.com"""
 
 Set oNodes = oXML.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("ssc:CTe")
 
 For Each oItem In oNodes
  MsgBox oItem.nodeName
 Next

End Sub
```

There using

```
oXMLFile.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:ssc=""http://www.somesite.com"""
```

I define a prefix `ssc` for the namespace

`http://www.somesite.com`.

The `scc` is my own choice (**s**ome**s**ite.**c**om). This prefix is needed for the `XPATH` in `selectNodes` method to work properly.

If you don't want defining the namespace, you would must use the `local-name()` XPath function. For example:

```
Set oNodes = oXML.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("*[local-name() = 'CTe']")
```